# "No outputs have backlight property" but xorg.conf is configured and xbacklight is installed

Tags: debian, backlight

I'm using a Lenovo laptop with Intel video drivers, and I'm trying to control the brightness. I installed the `xbacklight` and `xserver-xorg-video-intel` packages, added these lines to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

and I verified that the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/` directory does exist. When I run `xbacklight`, I get the error:

```
No outputs have backlight property
```

How do I configure the backlight? I'm using Debian 9 x64 and the system is fully up to date.

EDIT: I can manually change the brightness by elevating my permissions with `sudo` and writing to the `brightness` file:

```
echo 500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

EDIT: I get the same "No outputs have backlight property" if I run `xbacklight` as root or with `sudo`.

Comment: Not all drivers implement backlight. Are you sure you are using Intel and not framebuffer?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm not sure. How do I check? I assumed that the `intel_backlight` directory meant that I was using Intel drivers.

Comment: Have you tried running xbacklight using `sudo` or as root ?

Comment: @cesar Yes. I get the same errors. I updated the question to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There can be numerous reason why this doesn't work, and they are all to complicated to ask in a comment to the question, so I'll leave this as a resource here - and if none of these work feel free to comment rather than down-voting and I'll remove it *(or leave for others who end up here with the same problem but different causes)*.

The first thing you can try is adding one of these kernel parameters:

```
acpi_osi=Linux
acpi_osi="!Windows 2012"
acpi_osi=
```

This is a pretty common issue where the backlight stops working after a suspend (I know this isn't directly related, but might be worth mentioning).

Another issue might be that you're lacking sufficient permission to actually modify the brightness *(again, probably not related to OP since the error message is usually different and OP has already tried it)*. If that's the case, modify the udev-rules by changing/adding this to `/etc/udev/rules.d/backlight.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="intel_backlight", RUN+="/bin/chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", KERNEL=="intel_backlight", RUN+="/bin/chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
```

Another, also common issue, is when used in conjunction with multiple graphic cards or hybrid graphics *(like the Optimus project)*.

If so, you can try to add one of the following kernel parameters:

```
acpi_backlight=video
acpi_backlight=vendor
acpi_backlight=native
acpi_backlight=none    # <-- Mainly for AMD/ATI drivers
```

---

Finally, what OP might be here for:

Change `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` to reflect:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics" 
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

Odds are xrandr or xbacklight have just got a faulty mapping against `/sys/class/backlight/<path>`. Thus, manually setting it to `intel_backlight` might solve your issue. All that might be wrong is the Identifier, judging by the question. If it still doesn't work, verify and make sure that the Device-config is actually the one in use, because it really sounds like a mapping issue between xrandr/xbacklight and the path where it thinks it'll find the backlight-directory.

Any of these might give you a clue or hint as to which driver and config is being used:

```
lspci | grep VGA
lsmod | grep "kms\|drm"
find /dev -group video
cat /proc/cmdline
find /etc/modprobe.d/
cat /etc/modprobe.d/*kms*
glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering"
grep LoadModule /var/log/Xorg.0.log
egrep -i " connected|card detect|primary dev|Setting driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/
```

I hope it's as simple as this; if it's not, again, I'd be happy to change my answer or delete it all together. Just sharing some knowledge gathered while struggling with the same thing. [bugs.debian.org issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=651741)

Oh, and the kernel parameter `nomodeset` tends to interfere with backlight settings. I don't know why. But if whoever ends up here uses it, try to remove that and see if at least the backlight kicks in again.

Comment: You may want to add to your "test and clues area" .... `udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/`

Comment: Good one @RubberStamp. Some times the simplest of tools gets you the furthest.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone finds this using Arch Linux, I simply replaced `xorg-backlight` with `acpilight`, and then `sudo backlight -set 10` works fine.

Comment: Finally, a solution for me! Also, one can run `sudo usermod -aG video USERNAME` to avoid having to run sudo on `backlight -set 50` etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Every step required for `xbacklight` control

Follow these steps:

1. `$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and [replace the corresponding line with](https://askubuntu.com/a/426266/164341) `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
2. `$ sudo update-grub`
3. No joking, make sure that the [appropriate drivers are actually installed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851810#25): `$ sudo apt install xbacklight xorg xserver-xorg-video-intel`
4. Issuing `$ find /sys -type f -name brightness` should yield something like `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness`
5. `$ cd /sys/class` This directory should contain a soft link called `brightness` to the brightness device discovered in the previous step. Should it be missing, create it: `$ sudo ln -s /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness /sys/class/brightness`
6. `$ sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf` should read:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Device0"
    Driver          "intel"
    Option          "Backlight"      "intel_backlight"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen0"
    Monitor         "Monitor0"
    Device          "Device0"
EndSection
```

7. The assignment of the physical `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` keys is [explained here for Xubuntu LTS or XFCE users](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080149/164341).
8. Finally, **reboot** for these changes to take effect.

Comment: Even as root, creating the soft link in step 5 returns an error: `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'brightness': Operation not permitted`