# Remap backlight/brightness to other keys on XFCE

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, brightness, backlight

I have a laptop with Manjaro XFCE and I damaged my `F2` and `F3` keys, which operate the brightness of the display (up and down respectively) while holding the `Fn` key.

The `xfce-power-manager` works fine, and I can use the slider on the bottom bar, but I would like to know if I can remap brightness to other keys. I haven't been able to find a solution for now.

I tried instaling [light](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/light/) package, as I saw in another reply, and using:

```
light -U 20
```

decreases the brightness as expected, but it has to be done as root, so my idea to remap that command to another key combination, doesn't work, because it doesn't have privileges.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight#xbacklight maybe? You could add shortcuts for `xbacklight -inc 5` and `xbacklight -dec 5`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I tried that, but I got the "No outputs have backlight property" that the wiki talks about. But I don't have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-video.conf`, and creating it with the suggested content doesn't change the output (same "no outputs have backlight property" error)

Comment: Please report here https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues

Comment: As [commented here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507333), using `acpilight` package instead of `xorg-backlight` package in **Arch** made the commands `xbacklight -inc 10` (and the decrease option) work. But again as with `light` package, I need sudo. I havn't been able to edit `sudoers` in a way that my user can run (just) that script without sudo. But that is another problem. If nobody has another idea, I will explore how to run a script like that.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". If you have a solution then consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later (don't add it into the question). Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see  https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer  You should be able to simply copy the text from [your most recent revision of the question text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/667022/3) and make a separate answer from that.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry, I didn't knew I should answer my own post. And I don't know if  there is a way one can recover all the markup format of a given revision. I don't find how to and having to put all the URLs, sections, format and everything back again... -.-. Maybe next time give the warning and give one day or so to do it? It's a real pain to put again all the markup code.

Comment: @PolGZ You can see all revision of your text by clicking the text saying [edited ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/667022/revisions) underneath the text. There you will be able to switch between seeing the markup text or the rendered text.  There will be no next time, so no need for advance warning :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda I really don't see an edit option in the [revision of the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/667022/3). And in the edit of any "current" question, I can only see what there really is "at that moment", not the previous ones. But anyway, thanks for all your notes and I don't believe it will be a next time 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got to a solution. Here is what I did (better ways would be welcome!)

1. Instead of `xorg-xbacklight` package as showed [in the Arch Wiki as default option](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight#xbacklight) (because I got the error *"no outputs have backlight property"* that the wiki talks about, and using the .conf parameters showed in the wiki didn't solve it for me) **I installed: [acpilight](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/acpilight/) package**. It runs the same way as xorg-xbacklight:

   - `xbacklight -inc 10` to increase, and
   - `xbacklight -dec 10` to decrease. As suggested by @ArtemS.Tashkinov here in the comments.
2. To control xbacklight and chenge backlight level, you need **sudo privileges**, so I needed to **edit `sudoers`** to make my user able to run the `xbacklight` command without asking for the password (but, for security reasons, of course, only that, and not any command):

   1. `sudo visudo` (vim like editor) or `su` and then `visudo` (with your default editor, in case your are used to nano)
   2. Add the following (changing `username` for your user):

      ```
      username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xbacklight
      ```
3. To avoid the possible error (I had it) `/usr/bin/xbacklight: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'`; I **added my user to the `video` group**, which is the default in 90-backlight.rules [(as I saw here)](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight/-/issues/16#note_96203690) (change `username` for your user name):

   ```
   sudo usermod –a –G video username
   ```
4. **Create two scripts** called `bright-up.sh` and `bright-down.sh` (or whatever you want), with this content:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash

   xbacklight -inc 10
   ```

   - Change `-inc` for `-dec` in the bright-down.sh
   - Change `10` for the value you want, like `5` or `20`, depending on how much you want the brightness to change.
5. Place those scripts in a directory like `/home/user/.bin/` or wherever you want and give them **execute permissions**:

   ```
   chmod +x /home/user/.bin/brigh-up.sh /home/user/.bin/bright-down.sh
   ```
6. Now **create keyboard shortcuts** pointing to those scripts according to your desktop environment/window manager. In XFCE in keyboard > keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful on Gnome too. I can now change the brightness but I don't get the on screen notification with the slider moving. Do you know how to get this further step?

Comment: @Pablohoney Sorry, I only have Gnome on a Debian desktop system, so I can't test it. Maybe try using gnome dconf and directly bind brightness-keys to your prefered combination as showed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/sia8qj/comment/hv7pdo6/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)? Instead of using my scripts.

If not, try reading [this old ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400268/how-to-enable-notifications-while-changing-brightness-and-or-volume) or [this arch post using another notification daemon](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=125115)

Comment: Ok, the solution of the first link works. Thank you.