# Dell XPS 9360 FN brightness keys not detected Manjaro

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, manjaro, brightness, backlight

I have Manjaro installed in dual boot on a Dell XPS 9360 with FHD screen non touchscreen. The key combo to increase/decrease the screen brightness are `Fn+F11` and `Fn+F12`. This works perfectly on Windows 11 and Ubuntu but not on Manjaro

So far I can adjust the brightness from the slider in the notification area of the top bar (I'm using Gnome with Wayland, same as ubuntu where Fn key combo it works perfectly also for brightness; on X I have the same problem so it's not some wayland related issue) and adjust it through `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`
I can also change the brightness through xbacklight, but still not with Fn key combo

Looks like that the Fn+F key combo is not detected at all, like it's not registered anywhere

- in `xev` the pushing of `Fn+F11` or F12 isn't even detected
- `acpi_listen` reports `9 DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000` for both `Fn+F11` and `Fn+F12`; at least it detects something but I know it's not the right thing as if I push Fn+F3 (to increase the spearkers volume) it gives `button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K` meaning that it somehow associates that key combo to a specific event/action.
  `9 DBB5994-A997- 000000d0 00000000` is the same result if I push Fn+F10 which is the combo to adjust keyboard brightness, but this works flawlessly

I've also tried the following, without any success

- add `acpi_backlight=none`, `acpi_backlight=vendor`, `acpi_backlight=video` and `acpi_backlight=native` to `/etc/default/grub` in the section `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
- add `acpi_osi=` and `acpi_osi=Linux` alone and in combination with one of the previous keys to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`; to be honest I've not tried all the combinations (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142017/brightness-keys-f4-and-f5-not-working-on-dell-xps-15-6-laptop) for example), so you tell me if it's the case
- configure /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf as auggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/clj91c/brightness_buttons_stopped_working_dell_xps_15/) but nothing

Thank you for your help

Comment: EDIT: I've **partially** solved following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667022/remap-backlight-brightness-to-other-keys-on-xfce?rq=1), now I can adjust the brightness with the combo `Alt+F11`, the brightness actually changes but I don't get the slider moving and anyway I wasn't able to set `Fn+F12` as shortcut, like it wasn't detected

Comment: EDIT2: Thanks to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/sia8qj/arch_gnome_no_brightness_shortcuts/hv7pdo6/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I managed to bind a combination like `Super`+`F11` To screen brightness down and get back the notification, thanks to @PolGZ
Now what I want to understand is how to get back the regular functioning of `Fn`+`F11` or `F12` key combo